# How to access token saved as a variable in different dart page in a secured storage

Tags: flutter, dart

I have saved a token as a variable in flutter secure storage in a file called `login_response_model.dart` and I am trying to access it in the home screen, but I keep getting error as undefined name:

Here is the `login_response_model.dart`:

```
class LoginResponse {
  dynamic? key;
  List<dynamic>? non_field_errors;
  LoginResponse({this.key, this.non_field_errors});

  factory LoginResponse.fromJson(mapOfBody) {
    return LoginResponse(
      key: mapOfBody['key'],
      non_field_errors: mapOfBody['non_field_errors'],
    );
  }
}

LoginResponseModel loginResponseJson(String str) =>
    LoginResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

class LoginResponseModel {
  dynamic? key;
  List<dynamic>? non_field_errors;
  LoginResponseModel({this.key, this.non_field_errors});

  LoginResponseModel.fromJson(mapOfBody) {
    key:
    mapOfBody['key'];
    non_field_errors:
    mapOfBody['non_field_errors'];
    print(mapOfBody['key']);

    // Create storage
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    // Write value
    storage.write(key: 'Token', value: mapOfBody['key']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['key'] = key;
    _data['non_field_errors'] = non_field_errors;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Data {
  Data({
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.date,
    required this.id,
    required this.key,
  });
  late final String username;
  late final String email;
  late final String date;
  late final String id;
  late final String key;

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    username = json['username'];
    email = json['email'];
    date = json['date'];
    id = json['id'];
    key = json['key'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['username'] = username;
    _data['email'] = email;
    _data['date'] = date;
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['key'] = key;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

Here is the homescreen:

```
Future<User> fetchUser() async {
  var url = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL + Config.userProfileAPI);
  var value = storage.read(key: 'Token');
```

**My question:**

How can I access the token saved in a secured storage into the home screen?
Is there an easier and more secure way to access the token saved other than the way I have arranged it?

Answer (score 1):

Use can you `SharedPreference` & save token here. Each time you want to use, you just need to:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String token = prefs.getString("key_token") ?? "";
```

However, each time you want to use it, you again need to use async function & wait until it give you saved token. Although it doesn't take so much time & space but we need to notice this. You can init a global variable to save token whenever open app or login success. Learn more about `Singleton`.

Example in my app: `data_instance.dart`

```
class DataInstance {

    static DataInstance _instance = new DataInstance.internal();

    DataInstance.internal();

    factory DataInstance() => _instance;

    late String accessToken;
    initPreference() async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        DataInstance().accessToken = prefs.getString("key_token_haha")?? '';
    }
}
```

In `main.dart`:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await DataInstance().initPreference();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```